# Integrating gRPC with Spring Data Jpa for Persistence Layer

Tags: spring-data-jpa, grpc, grpc-java

I am new to gRPC and I am building a microservice application using Spring Boot. The plan is to use gRPC to create shared entity classes across the microservices. I would like to ask, are the classes generated by gRPC annotated with @Entity annotation and other JPA annotations?

If the above is possible, will I also be able to selectively choose to exclude the JPA annotations? this is because some microservices do not need the entity of other microservices.

Furthermore, what are the best practices for gRPC in Spring Boot? E.g. the libraries available etc.

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible to annotate classes generated by protobuffer, but you can exted the classes generated and annotated those. Moreover, have you seen this https://github.com/yidongnan/grpc-spring-boot-starter ?

Comment: @Felipe thanks for replying! I have found https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter. What are the differences between the libraries and which library is recommended?